# How can I create close button on Menu bar?

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qmenubar

In the picture below, the red rectangle is the menu bar. I want to create close button where the green rectangle is, but I don't know how can I do that. Any suggestions? I'd like to make the UI look like Adobe Photoshop CS6?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: MenuBar is simple widget. So... 1) Create a widget with MenuBar and your button inside. 2) Insert a button to the right side of MenuBar (+process related resize events)

Comment: I'm very newbie. How can I create a widget with MenuBar and my button inside? and What is "+process related resize events" Thanks

Comment: `QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton( pMenuBar );`

Comment: Can you give me an example code. Please, I'm very in trouble. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The QMenuBar widget has a method "setCornerWidget", You can do what you want like this:

```
    // Hiden Window Title
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    // Set widget on the top left corner
    QPushButton* menuTopRightButton = new QPushButton("TL", m_menubar);
    m_menubar->setCornerWidget(menuTopRightButton, Qt::TopLeftCorner);

    // Set widget on the top right corner
    QPushButton* menuTopLeftButton = new QPushButton("TR", m_menubar);
    m_menubar->setCornerWidget(menuTopRightButton, Qt::TopRightCorner);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#closeButton {
position: absolute;
height:20px;
width:100px;
background:red;
float:right;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6U5p8/

Comment: Thank You but how can I insert <div id="close">X</div> in my UI

Comment: Are you talking about Qt program in c++?

Comment: Oh, my bad: i'm sorry, thought it was HTML/CSS. :$

Comment: @douwe12345 while this may answer the question it's usually better to give a brief description along with any code posted. It will help future visitors better understand why your answer is correct and may even give you a few upvotes :)

Comment: @douwe12345: if this answer isn't relevant whatsoever I suggest you deleted it altogether.